Rails 6, how to render .js.erb with fetch() and params
I am updating old Rails apps that worked with jquery and $ajax(), and this still works after the update. I would like to change the ajax call for a fetch() with .js.erb and params, all seems well, but the html does not get replaced by the workbar_work partial. Any suggestions?
in controller:
def switch_state
  permitted_params = params.permit(:partial)
  @partial = permitted_params[:partial].to_s
  @exercise = current_exercise  # defined somewhere else
  respond_to do |format|
     format.js
  end
end

in switch_state.js.erb
$('#workbar_switch').html("<%= j render(partial: @partial, :locals => {exercise: @exercise@}) %>");

the fetch call
function switchState(partial, exercise){
  const params = new URLSearchParams();
  params.append('partial', partial);

  fetch("/work/switch_state", {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'text/javascript, application/javascript, application/ecmascript, application/x-ecmascript',
        'X-CSRF-Token': document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content,
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    body: params
  })
  .then(response =>  {
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
    }
    return response.text()
  })  
  .then(responseText => {
    console.log("received js", responseText)
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log('Update failed', error)
    console.log('error', error.message)
  })
  .finally(() => {
  })
}

rails server log - seems to look ok:
Started POST "/work/switch_state" for ::1 at 2024-12-07 11:19:49 +0100
Processing by WorkController#switch_state as JS
  Parameters: {"partial"=>"workbar_work"}
  Exercise Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "exercises".* FROM "exercises" WHERE "exercises"."unit" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["unit", "ct100_1_ma3"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/models/exercise.rb:81:in `find_exercise'
  CACHE Exercise Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "exercises".* FROM "exercises" WHERE "exercises"."unit" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["unit", "ct100_1_ma3"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/models/exercise.rb:81:in `find_exercise'
  Rendering work/switch_state.js.erb
  Rendered work/_workbar_work.html.erb (Duration: 0.6ms | Allocations: 351)
  CACHE Exercise Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "exercises".* FROM "exercises" WHERE "exercises"."unit" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["unit", "ct100_1_ma3"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/models/exercise.rb:81:in `find_exercise'
  Rendered work/switch_state.js.erb (Duration: 3.4ms | Allocations: 2535)
Completed 200 OK in 17ms (Views: 5.4ms | ActiveRecord: 2.1ms | Allocations: 9998)

browser console:
  [Log] response – Response {type: "basic", url: "http://localhost:3000/work/switch_state", redirected: false, …} (ctrl-dc34a42ad73de8380cf755f815535ed1b8bfc04007d2b4f4fad4a1f130e93d45.js, line 183)
  [Log] received js – "$('#workbar_switch').html(\"<ul>\\n\t\\n\t<a title=\\\"Klicke hier für eine leichte Übung\\\" id=\\\"bug_click\\\" href=\\\"\\\">\\n\t<l…" (ctrl-dc34a42ad73de8380cf755f815535ed1b8bfc04007d2b4f4fad4a1f130e93d45.js, line 190)
  "$('#workbar_switch').html(\"<ul>\\n  \\n <a title=\\\"Klicke hier für eine leichte Übung\\\" id=\\\"bug_click\\\" href=\\\"\\\">\\n  <li id=\\\"workbar_bug\\\">\\n      <i class=\\\"fa fa-bug\\\"><\\/i>\\n        <span id=\\\"bug_text\\\"><\\/span>\\n  <\\/li>\\n<\\/a>    <a title=\\\"andere Stufe\\\" id=\\\"back_to_base_click\\\" href=\\\"\\\">\\n   <li id=\\\"change_level\\\">\\n     <i class=\\\"fa fa-signal\\\"><\\/i>\\n     <span>andere Stufe<\\/span>\\n  <\\/li>\\n<\\/a>    \\n<\\/ul>\\n\\n<form id=\\\"answerForm\\\"\\n        name=\\\"answerForm\\\"\\n      action=\\\"#dummy\\\">\\n\\n  <div id= \\\"answer_field\\\"\\n              title= \\\"Tippe Deine Antwort hier\\\">\\n         <input type = \\\"text\\\"\\n                     id = \\\"txtanswer\\\"\\n                   name = \\\"txtanswer\\\"\\n                     size = \\\"3\\\"\\n                     maxlength = \\\"3\\\" />\\n              <\\/div>\\n  \\n  <button type=\\\"submit\\\" \\n          id=\\\"submit_answer\\\">\\n    <i class=\\\"fa fa-level-down fa-rotate-90\\\"><\\/i>\\n    <span>OK<\\/span>\\n  <\\/button>\\n\\n<\\/form>\\n\\n\");"


The JavaScript returned by the AJAX call is not going to magically execute itself. That's would be really terrible for security.
When Rails UJS handles AJAX responses it creates a script tag and attaches it to the document which evals the script:
const script = document.createElement("script");
script.setAttribute("nonce", cspNonce());
script.text = response;
document.head.appendChild(script).parentNode.removeChild(script);

This is basically just an evolution of the JSONP technique used to do cross-domain requests for JSON way back in the dark ages cludged into a (very) poor mans AJAX framework.
If you want to build on the tower of wonkyness that is js.erb templates it would be way easier to just create a form with JS or have it hidden on the page and trigger a submit to get Rails UJS to handle it for you instead of writing AJAX handlers with fetch.
Or you could just not wrap your HTML chunk in JavaScript like a sane person.
def switch_state
  permitted_params = params.permit(:partial) 
  @partial = permitted_params[:partial].to_s # this is super sketchy 
  # a malicous user could use this for code execution or to print things like config files.
  # NEVER accept paths to files from the interwebs.
  @exercise = current_exercise  # defined somewhere else
  render(
    content_type: "text/html"
    partial: @partial, 
    locals: { exercise: @exercise@ },
    layout: false
  )
end

function switchState(partial, exercise){
  const params = new URLSearchParams();
  params.append('partial', partial);

  fetch("/work/switch_state", {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'text/html',
        'X-CSRF-Token': document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content,
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    body: params
  })
  // ...
  .then(responseText => {
    $('#workbar_switch').html(responseText);
  })
}

This is what Turbo does.

Thank you Max, I am not attached to .js.erb - they sit in these old apps that started with Rails 2. In fact, I want to replace with stimulus and turbo, but step by step.
Even if in the end fetch would be redundant, I still would like to learn how to use it properly, if you don't mind.
How do you find out what is or has become wonky?
Is it better to send data as json? if so, why?

Well, we always kind of knew that the Rails UJS way of doing AJAX was pretty wonky. It "worked" but lead to some really stinky design where you spread your JS all over your views and create a bunch of routes in your rails app that serve to just update a little button or something else on the frontend that should never have concerned the server.

Sending data as JSON isn't objectively better. The choice really boils down to if you want to use your server to handle templating and avoid duplication or if you want the server to just be responsible for delivering data. If you want to learn how to use the fetch api I would really just create a simple one page app where you consume some publically available JSON api instead of trying to do it in a legacy app. For the legacy app I would just patch things up as good as possible and try to update to Rails 7 ASAP.

that's absolutely what I am trying to do!! but I am a curious person and have trouble resisting finding out about stuff... thanks! and: javascript in Rails has been a headache from one version to the next. Fingers crossed

I see @partial = "workbar_work". When render (partial: workbar_work, ...) is not found, the _workbar_work.html.erb file. Because it is inside the work folder

$('#workbar_switch').html("<%= j render(partial: "work/#{@partial}", :locals => {exercise: @exercise@}) %>");

or
You can set @partial = "work/#{permitted_params[:partial].to_s}"

$('#workbar_switch').html("<%= j render(partial: @partial, :locals => {exercise: @exercise@}) %>");

